# Prove that f(x)=0 has exactly 3 solutions

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I need to prove that tan(x)=10x has exactly 3 solutions in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$:

I declared $f(x)=\tan(x)-10x$

1. I have proved that $f(x)=0$ has at least 3 solution using the fact that it's odd and continuous function.
2. Now I need to prove that there can't be 4 solutions, I remember a rule that says if $f(x)=0$ in four points then f'(x)=0 in three point in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ but how may I continue from here?

Note: $f'(x)=\frac1{\cos^2 x}-10$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the function is odd and since $f(0)=0$ we have that $x_1=0$ is a root.

Then for $x>0$ we have:

- $f\left(\frac \pi 4\right)<0$
- $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)= \infty$
- $f'(x)=\frac1{\cos^2 x}-10=0 \iff \cos x=\frac1{\sqrt {10}}$

therefore $f(x)$ has a negative minimum and by IVT a second root exists $x_2\in\left(\frac \pi 4, \frac \pi 2\right)$ and then a third one $x_3=-x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

On $[0, \frac {\pi} 2]$ there is a unique point where $cos^{2}(x)=\frac  1{10}$. [$\cos x$ decreases strictly fron $1$ to $0$ in this interval].   Same is true in $[- \frac {\pi} 2, 0]$. So there are exactly two points in $[- \frac {\pi} 2,\frac {\pi} 2]$ where $f'(x)=0$.